# ASP.NET MVC and MemoryCache - how do i use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memorycache

I have this in my Application_Start:

```
var crumbsCache = new MemoryCache("breadCrumbsNames");
var crumbsList = new List<CacheItem>
                    {
                        //list of new CacheItem();
                    };
foreach (var cacheItem in crumbsList)
{
    crumbsCache.Add(cacheItem, new CacheItemPolicy());
}
```

Now, in my controllers i am doing this:

```
var cache = new MemoryCache("breadCrumbsNames");
var cacheItem = cache.GetCacheItem("nameOfCacheItem");
```

But then cacheItem is always null, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this http://www.deanhume.com/home/blogpost/object-caching----net-4/37

Answer (score 12):

I think a better option for you would be to use `Ninject` or some other dependency injection framework to inject your `MemoryCache` into the controllers as needed.

You will begin by adding `Ninject` and `Ninject.Mvc3` (and any other related bits) to your ASP.NET MVC project. If you are working in Visual Studio, you can use NuGet to do that. It is quite painless and well-automated.

The next step will be to wrap your `MemoryCache` into some kind of a interface, such as:

```
public interface IMemoryCacheService
{
    MemoryCache MemoryCache
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class MemoryCacheService : IMemoryCacheService
{
    public MemoryCacheService()
    {
        MemoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    }

    public MemoryCache MemoryCache
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then you define a binding within Ninject so that Ninject knows that when you need something of type `IMemoryCacheService`, it should give you the instance of `MemoryCacheService`.

I will paste my own Ninject config class here. The one that will be created in your project will be very similar and will be in a folder called `App_Start` (which will be created automatically if you use NuGet). The class that Ninject creates by default is called `NinjectWebCommon`.

```
public static class NinjectConfig
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));

        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>()
              .ToMethod(context => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>()
              .To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        kernel.RegisterServices();

        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(this IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IMemoryCacheService>()
              .To<MemoryCacheService>()
              .InSingletonScope();
              // InSingletonScope() is important so Ninject knows
              // to create only one copy and then reuse it every time
              // it is asked for

        // ignore the stuff below... I have left it in here for illustration
        kernel.Bind<IDbTransactionFactory>()
              .To<DbTransactionFactory>()
              .InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IDbModelContext>()
              .To<DbModelContext>()
              .InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IDbModelChangeContext>()
              .To<DbModelChangeContext>()
              .InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IUserContext>()
              .To<UserContext>()
              .InRequestScope();

        kernel.BindAttributeAndFilter<IgnoreNonAjaxRequestsFilter, IgnoreNonAjaxRequestsAttribute>();
        kernel.BindAttributeAndFilter<ProvideApplicationInfoFilter, ProvideApplicationInfoAttribute>();
        kernel.BindAttributeAndFilter<ProvideSessionInfoFilter, ProvideSessionInfoAttribute>();
        kernel.BindAttributeAndFilter<UseDialogLayoutFilter, UseDialogLayoutAttribute>();
        kernel.BindAttributeAndFilter<CheckResourceAccessFilter, CheckResourceAccessAttribute>();
        kernel.BindAttributeAndFilter<CheckResourceStateFilter, CheckResourceStateAttribute>();
    }

    private static void BindAttributeAndFilter<TFilter, TAttribute>(this IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.BindFilter<TFilter>(FilterScope.Action, null)
              .WhenControllerHas<TAttribute>();
        kernel.BindFilter<TFilter>(FilterScope.Action, null)
              .WhenActionMethodHas<TAttribute>();
    }
}
```

Finally, your controllers will change from:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

to:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCacheService memoryCacheService;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCacheService memoryCacheService)
    {
        this.memoryCacheService = memoryCacheService;
    }

    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        // use this.memoryCacheService in your controller methods...
    }

    ...
}
```

Say, you made another service as well called `IEmailService` following the above-mentioned strategy, and you wanted `IEmailService` to be available in `HomeController` as well, then:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCacheService memoryCacheService;
    private IEmailService emailService;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCacheService memoryCacheService, IEmailService emailService)
    {
        this.memoryCacheService = memoryCacheService;
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        // use this.memoryCacheService in your controller methods...
        // and also use this.emailService in your controller methods...
    }

    ...
}
```

Ninject will change the ASP.NET MVC controller factory to automatically provide the injected arguments to the controller constructors.

I think this sort of approach is better in the long run that keeping global variables, etc.

Comment: I'm of the opinion this adds more overhead than value for most situations. [Edited to add: this may be appropriate for distributed caches.]

Just use MemoryCache.Default as described by Ryan Byrne.

Comment: I wrote all of the above more to illustrate the right approach than to answer the specific question, if I am honest. The core problem was that the OP was trying to create an object in a controller (which would be per-request) whereas he needed a singleton. In general, we want to be injecting dependencies, rather than using static classes/properties.

Comment: Further, if you read the comment by the OP on Ryan Byrne's answer, it is quite clear that (probably unbeknownst to the OP) the OP is looking for a DI mechanism, rather than just a properly initialized global variable.

Answer (score 10):

You are creating a new instance of `MemoryCache` in each controller. Since it is new there is nothing in it which is why you values are always null. You need to access the same instance that you created in `Application_Start`. Look into using `MemoryCache.Default`.

Comment: But what exactly is `MemoryCache.Default`? If i would set up two different instances of memcache, how would `MemoryCache.Default` know which one is default?

Comment: Set MemoryCache.Default equal to the instance you want to use.